# C++: Variable initialization using x{0}

Tags: c++

I saw a initialization syntax which is new for me. I searched on google and here but I couldn't find something useful.

```
int a = 0;
int a = {0};
int a{0}; // <- this is new for me
```

Why do I need third style while others exist? What is the difference between each exactly?

Thanks.

Comment: The third one solves what Scott Meyers called "C++'s most vexing parse."  Under certain circumstances, `int a(var)` could be misinterpreted as a function declaration rather than constructing a variable.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be interested by [C++11 initializer lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Initializer_lists). They might not explain the third example, but they are useful, especially for real class objects.

Your code `int a{0};` is called [uniform initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Uniform_initialization) in C++11. See also [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) wikipage (as commented by [Joe Z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2354107/joe-z)).

Take time to at least read the [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) wikipage. The new features of C++11 makes it almost a different language than C++03.

Answer (score 2):

This form of initialization is referred to as **list initialization** in C++11.

When used with variables of built-in type, list initialization is different in one way: you can't list initialize variables of built-in type if the initializer might lead to the loss of information.

```
double pi = 3.1415926;
int a(pi); //fine
int a{pi}; //compile error
```