# Why curly braces around the assignment of an enum in C++?

Tags: c++, enums, variable-assignment, curly-braces

I am looking at some code, and see assignment of an enum to a varaible.

Let's just say `x = y;` where `y` is an enum.

Except that it actually says `x = { y } ;`. My C++ is a little rusty (too much Ada). Are those braces actually required? If so, why?  I believe the code to be C++ 11 or 14.

Comment: Is `y` a plain-old `enum`, or an `enum class`?

Comment: [Why is list initialization (using curly braces) better than the alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18222926/995714), [C++: Variable initialization using `x{0}`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20392537/995714)

Comment: You say a lot about `y`, yet little to nothing about `x`, which is equally as important here.

Comment: Hour long presentation [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs) by Nicolai Josuttis at CppCon 2018.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica it is astructriue ember of the same type as the enum being assigned to it. I ought to have mentioned that the code compiles & Lints warning free